# findMax reduce to sort

Tags: reductions, sorting, lower-bounds

Can I reduce the find max (or find min) problem to the sort problem? Because if so, knowing the lower bound for find max is Ω(n) I can also infer that the lower bound for sorting is Ω(n) too?

I'm confused with this spread of lower bounds and applicability of reductions.

Comment: In several computation models you can get better lower bounds on sorting: $\Omega(n\log n)$.

Comment: That's ok. But I'm more interested in spreading this lower bound, as I soo it happening here J.2: https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~rezende/ensino/mo619/2008s1/x10-reductions2.pdf and here slide 20: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr08/cos226/lectures/23Reductions-2x2.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

After you sort an array, the minimum can be found in the first position, and the maximum can be found in the last position. This reduces finding the minimum and maximum to sorting an array. However, sorting is actually more difficult than just finding the minimum or maximum, so it's not clear what this reduction is good for.

Comment: But it stills a valid reduction, right?

Comment: This depends on your definition of reduction.

Comment: The definitions I saw meant that you must make one call of the reduced version and have a limited number of steps to transform the input and output

Comment: This is not quite a formal definition.

Comment: Could you please introduce me one?

Comment: You are the one asking whether a reduction exists. To make this question precise, you need to explain what a reduction is for you.

Comment: But most probably, what I outlined in the answer would constitute a reduction.

Comment: Maybe I understand know, even if you say that Ω(n) is a lower bound for sorting (in comparison computational model), it doesn't mean that there's an algorithm that runs in linear time. Ω only means that you can't make better than it.

Comment: That's right. If you want an upper bound on sorting, you need to reducing sorting to some other problem, which is exactly the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

You've mostly got it. You also have to add in the time that the reduction takes: usually reductions are to show that something is in $P$ vs $NP$, so what matters is "poly-time" versus "not poly-time", but here you're going more fine-grained.

This is the basic structure you're looking for:

- You can solve `FindMax` by calling `Sort` and then doing $O(1)$ work (taking the first/last element of the array, depending which way your sorting goes).
- Therefore, if you could solve `Sort` in less than $O(n)$ time, you could solve `FindMax` in less than $O(n)$ time.
- It's known that `FindMax` can't be done in less than $O(n)$.
- Therefore, you can't solve `Sort` in less than $O(n)$.